# Right align font-awesome spinner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How to right align the font-awesome spinner, so it will be on the right hand side of a button

Here is not working code:

```html
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
          <div><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

While the code above works, the spinner is always on the left hand side of the button, try so many different ways to achieve that

Comment: Try to pull-right class to icon

Comment: Have you tried adding `display:inline-block` to the button and div with the spinner inside.

Comment: tried both, none of them works

Comment: Seems worth noting that the `fa-li` class is only intended to be used with a `fa-ul` parent - it's for using [Font Awesome icons in place of the normal list item markers](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the class **fa-li** is what was causing the the problem, it makes the icon have a `position:absolute` and it position it on the left

So you need to remove the class.

and if you want it to be displayed inside the button than move `i` tag inside `button` tag

**see code snippet**:

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
     Sign up <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or just put it outside and it will be next to the button

**See code snippet:**

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
         Sign up 
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking, will mark the answer in 2 min, thank you